# Tableview checkmark wrong place

Tags: swift, uitableview, checkmark

I tried like so to add checkMark on cell but if I tap section 0 row 0,
section 2 row 0 also checked. Also if tap section 0 row 1, section 3 row 0 checked(vise verse if I tap section 2 row 0,
section 0 row 0 also checked also if tap section 3 row 0, section 0 row 1 checked).

And if scrolling fast all check goes away.
How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

        var sectionName = ["Cars", "Motor Cycles", "EV", "Hybrid"]
        var cars = ["TOYOTA", "AUDI", "BMW", "HONDA", "VOLVO", "VW","FIAT"]
        var motorCycles = ["YAMAHA", "HONDA", "DUCATI", "HARLEY DAVIDSON", "VICTORY"]
        var yes = "YES"

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self

        }



        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return sectionName.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return sectionName[section]
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            if section == 0 {
                return cars.count
            } else if section == 1 {
                return motorCycles.count
            } else {
                return 1
            }

        }

        let cellId = "cell"

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
            let section = indexPath.section

            if section == 0 {
                cell.textLabel?.text = cars[indexPath.row]
            } else if section == 1 {
                cell.textLabel?.text = motorCycles[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                cell.textLabel?.text = yes
            }

            return cell
        }

        var firstArray = [String?]()
        var secondArray = [String?]()
        var thirdString = ""
        var fourthString = ""

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            let section = indexPath.section
            let text = currentCell!.textLabel!.text!

            if currentCell?.accessoryType == .checkmark {

                switch section {

                case 0:
                    firstArray = firstArray.filter( { $0 != text } )
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .none
                case 1:
                    secondArray = secondArray.filter( { $0 != text } )
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .none

                case 2:
                    thirdString = ""
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .none

                case 3:
                    fourthString = ""
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .none

                default:
                    break

                }

            } else {

                switch section {

                case 0:
                    firstArray.append(text)
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                case 1:
                    secondArray.append(text)
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

                case 2:
                    thirdString = text
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                case 3:
                    thirdString = text
                    currentCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

                default:
                    break

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to put checkMark setting logic inside `cellForRow` , as because of dequeuing un wanted cells may get checked , so in `didSelectRow` store Indexpath/s of one/s you want to check and reload the cell with the selected `IndexPath`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. but how can I define `text` ? app will crash because `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: the text comes from the array compare it directly

Comment: Do not reload the whole table view in `didSelectRow`. Just reload the one row.

Comment: Question.  In the Class definition, you declare the Class is the UITableViewDataSource and Delegate.  Then in viewDidLoad() you do the same.  Why is this done twice?  Additionally, you have to do it through Interface Builder as well if you have using it.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Your comment should be asked on the question, not this answer.